# Gender Recognition Using Depth Data

Tags: c#, opencv, kinect

I would like to know if there are some libraries or algorithms that can help me to develope a Gender Recognition using depth data.

Now I am using Kinect as my depth sensor images. I was using OpenCV as Face Recognition on other work and I found that OpenCV can detect gender also. But can OpenCV Image Processing process depth Image of face or 3D face ?

Comment: Not sure if it is what you need, but take a look at [SVM.NET](http://www.matthewajohnson.org/software/svm.html). It is only a classifier though, so you would need some way to extract features from your depth data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked on an application for facial recognition using depth images. What I did was to use Gabor filters for extracting the features and trained a SVM classifier with those features.

For extracting the features I applied Gabor filters of different orientations and scales and after that checked for variations in the dataset for the same location in image. If the value in a certain position of the face is similar throughout the dataset ignore it. It is useful to align the images before. I did that by detecting the eyes line and the nose tip (easy using depth information).

For any further information ask me.

Comment: What libraries did you use ? and do you create your own data set or take it from others data set ?